# Compare étale morphisms in Top and Schemes

Tags: schemes, topos-theory, etale-cohomology

Perhaps because I find the algebraic definition of étale morphisms (of schemes) hard to approach, I'm trying to bootstrap from my understanding of étale morphisms of topological spaces. In topological spaces, we have an equivalence of categories $\acute Et\downarrow X\cong\text{Sh}(X)$, the category of étale spaces over $X$ is equivalent to sheaves on $X$. This probably determines the étale topology uniquely, and seems to me a good way to motivate the definition. Then I would work out its description in terms of open sets.

Can I approach the definition of étale morphisms of schemes the same way? What is the category of étale schemes over scheme $X$ equivalent to? I suppose it is not sheaves on (the underlying topological space of) $X$.

Comment: I think you are conflating two slightly different words that, without diacritics, are both spelled "etale": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8039/what-is-a-section/8049#8049

Comment: @qiaochu: I don't think I am conflating "étalé" and "étale". Étale, (without second accent aigu), means something like "local isomorpism", depending on which category you are in. An étalé space over $X$ is, by definition, a topological space with an étale morphism to $X$. And with or without the second accent, we have an isomorphism to the category of sheaves on $X$. Do you disagree with any of those statements?

Comment: @qiaochu: should I instead say that "étalé space" is defined to mean the bundle of stalks of a sheaf? Ok, fine, but such a space always comes equipped with an étale morphism to the base.

Comment: As I explained [before](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/5929/which-is-the-right-definition-of-etale-morphism/#Item_2), I do not believe that it is standard to call local homeomorphisms "étale".

Comment: @ZhenLin: hm, I didn't pick up on that from your response on nForum. Ok, but even if this usage is not standard, I'm more interested in the categorical equivalence than what name we use to describe it. We have an equivalence between local homeomorphisms to a topological space and sheaves on that space. Do we have an analogous equivalence for étale morphisms to a scheme?

Comment: There is no such equivalence, as far as I know; and even if there were, it would have to involve the étale site, which would defeat the purpose of understanding étale morphisms.

Comment: The discussion at the beginning of http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/etale+geometric+morphism suggests that étale morphisms of toposes to sheaves on $X$ are in correspondence with étale morphisms of topological spaces. It also mentions étale morphisms of ringed toposes. Do we also have the same correspondence between étale morphisms of ringed toposes and étale morphisms of schemes or locally ringed spaces?